# Problems with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, analytics

I am creating an application where I cache the tweets of the users of my application and display them to their timeline page. I am currently using mongodb to store the tweets. Initially mongodb worked just fine but as the number of tweets exceed 10,000 I have some MongoCursor error showing up like the following

Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorTimeoutException' with message 'cursor timed out (timeout: 30000, time left: 0:0, status: 0)

Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'couldn't send query: Broken pipe'
Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'couldn't get response header'

I have used proper indexing. So what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you scanning the whole collection by that query? You should consider indexing as well as using `limit()` and `skip()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is this line

timeout: 30000

The query has been running too long and therefore has been terminated. I would check the following

1) your query is well indexed by using explain()
2) whether mongostat is reporting "idx miss %" which will indicate whether the indexes are in memory and whether you had to go to disk to traverse the index
3) whether mongostat is reporting a high "locked %"
4) whether you are disk bound, try running "iostat -x 2"

Comment: Well, I have increased the index and the performance has improved a bit. But I have this another problem, the time taken to fetch the data is varying. Sometimes the time that it takes is less than 1 sec, sometimes it takes more than 12-15 seconds. What could be the reason behind it. I think I have properly indexed every possible key

Comment: What can be the cause of "couldn't send query: Broken pipe" error message? I am facing this exception.

Answer (score 0):

The connection is timming out. For [MongoCursorTimeoutException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursortimeoutexception.php) refer to this link.

With `couldn't get response header` try and check if the database is still up and the network is connected and try the query again.

Comment: The database is up all the time. I don't know why it is timing out because I don't have more than 10 processes connecting to mongodb and getting the tweets.  I am running a cronjob fetching tweets every two minute interval which spawns 10 processes to fetch the tweets of say 10 individual users. And the mongocursor exception doesn't occur continuously, it occurs randomly at any time.

Comment: @rajan sthapit try and set the timeout to a higher value and see if the number of tweets required for this error to happen again increases